# Java thread memory calculation

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, memory-management

Is it possible to calculate memory consumption for each thread? Suppose I divided my task into 4 threads then I want to know how much memory consumption by each threads? I need it to know average and peak memory usage from my threads.

Comment: I donot think that it is possible to calculate on a per thread memory consumption. Threads  generally consume from a shared memory. Hence threads do not own any specific memory. If any threads work on a scope with variables, a memory profiler would help you get that information.

Comment: @papaya I think it is possible. At least an approximation. If you know what a thread does you know how many objects it creates. It is possible to create the object sizes. The memory for static instances and JVM overhead can be counted to the first thread.

Comment: @AndiCover That is true, like I said in my answer, the problem comes only when threads start relating/consuming from shared memory. Apart from that it is faily straightforward by using a memory profiler. 

Since OP has not mentioned JVM versions etc. This may be helpful. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes%28long%29

Comment: @AndiCover you can record, which objects it creates and their memory occupation, but that doesn’t say, which objects the threads *uses*. As papaya correctly said, the heap memory is a *shared* memory The first thread that uses `"foo"` will be the creator of the string object, all other threads will use the same object, even when the creator has stopped using it or even when the creator does not exist anymore. There can be arbitrary object exchanges between the threads and those objects are usually the objects which will persist, the temporary local objects are the first to be garbage collected

Comment: @AndiCover how can do that?

Answer (score 7):

As others noted, most objects live on the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP). That heap memory is shared across threads. So there is no way to identify which threads are responsible for the size of the heap.

But threads do get their own chunk of memory: the stack.

## Stack size

As I recall from presentations by Ron Pressler of Oracle in 2020…

### Conventional threads

Each thread is assigned a certain amount of memory for its [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). Since currently threads in Java implementations based on OpenJDK are mapped *one-to-one* to host OS’ thread, the stack size is arbitrarily set to something like a meg. More memory may be allocated if needed, but is not reduced.

### Virtual threads

The plot thickens with virtual threads ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) proposed in [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main).

Project Loom adds new capabilities to the Java concurrency facilities. As part of this, virtual threads are mapped *many-to-one* to host OS threads (a.k.a. platform/kernel threads). The [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) will manage these virtual threads rather than the OS, “parking” a virtual thread when its code blocks to allow time for another virtual thread to run via execution time assigned to the “real” platform/kernel thread. The scheduling of that “real” platform/kernel thread to actually get work done on the CPU core is controlled by the host OS, with or without Project Loom (at least in Java implementations based on [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)).

➥ As part of this JVM-management of virtual threads, each virtual thread's stack will start out much smaller. And each stack will grow, and shrink(!), as needed.

Because of this efficient use of both CPU and memory, virtual threads are dramatically "cheaper". So we can run more of them. Even millions of virtual threads are possible on common hardware.

Comment: Project Loom allows virtual threads to settle on arbitrary `Executor` implementations, like a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. So it’s a *many-to-many* relationship.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. now I understand how Java manage their memory for threads.

Answer (score 2):

Summing up my comment, threads use shared memory. Hence no thread owns any data of it's own apart from the reserved stack memory (which is set during jvm startup).

Since you are focussing on the exact heap size a thread consumes whilst running your jvm, you can simply rather use a memory profiler like [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/) to look at the classes & Objects which your thread creates and assume the consumption  size.

You can also [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables to define Objects belonging to a specific thread. This can also help you get the exact memory consumption on a per thread basis.

You can also look at [ThreadMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html), however this is no longer available in the latest jvms.

Comment: I think I exactly said that. Read again?

Comment: Yes, you did. I missed it, my mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I got the idea about the shared memory used by threads. About ThreadLocal, how can I calculate the memory consumption? if I call Runtime. getRuntime(). freeMemory() to that ThreadLocal, it will show overall free memory right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Native Memory Tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html) to get info about the threads in general, but I'm not sure how to get info about each thread individually.

Add `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics` to your vm options when starting your application:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -jar myjar.jar
```

Now, if you run:

```
$jps -l
```

to find the java process on your machine and then

```
$jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory
```

you will see something like the following:

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=2344374KB +4399KB, committed=567362KB +19659KB
...
- Thread (reserved=87894KB, committed=19126KB +756KB)
         (thread #159)
         (stack: reserved=87132KB, committed=18364KB +756KB)
         (malloc=577KB #956)
         (arena=184KB #316)
...
```

With this info you could do 19126KB/159=120KB to get an average committed size of memory for each thread. The problem is this won't tell you each thread individually and some threads will be larger and others smaller.

You can also use:

```
$jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory baseline
$jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory summary.diff
```

This would tell you the difference between a baseline instant of time and a run that you could do during peak traffic.

*One word of caution: Enabling NMT has some additional overhead associated with it. You may want to weigh the risks of running an application in PROD with that enabled.*